# SharePoint Designer Workflow copy data from one list field to another

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-server, custom-list

I have attempted to do this workflows and tried publishing a few but they cant seem to execute. I am not sure what the reason could be. I am trying to forward all values from one field in a list to another another field from another list?
Should I use lookup field to perform this workflow?

[image]

The workflow which I have published the list to displays the following below. Is this correct when you publish a workflow on the list?

[image]

Comment: On the second screenshot it seems there is no workflow published at all

Comment: I posted a tutorial about how to create your first workflow. Maybe that will help: https://afrait.com/blog/how-to-create-your-first-2013-workflow-de-en/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so you didn't provide much to go off (like whether this is a 2010 or 2013 WF and what you were trying to copy) but I've drafted up a 2013 WF that does what you want (you were on the right track)...

**Workflow Overview:**

[image: Workflow Overview]

**Create Item Details:**

[image: Create Item Details]

**Update List Item Details:**

[image: Update List Item Details]

Not sure if this is what you were looking for but I hope it helps!

Comment: Its a 2010 workflow which is done in sharepoint designer 2013. I tried a test workflow. it doesnt work. Im not sure whether there is a setting on sharepoint 2013??

Comment: Thank you for you comments. I am using WF 2010 with SharePoint Designer 2013. I think the workflow is not the problem, cause I tried a basic test workflow and it did not work. I read that you cannot use the System user account to do workflows in SharePoint. is this true?